# How to add together numerical values that are stored in strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add `1` to my JavaScript variable, but the following code doesn't give expected results:

```
var val1 = document.getElementById('<%= rng1.ClientID %>');
var val2 = val1.value + "1";
alert(val2.value);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying add one mathematically? Ie. 3 + 1 = 4. Or adding "1" to the end of a string? Ie. "3" + "1" = "31".

Comment: You are assigning either a string or a number to `val2`. Hence, it is not an object and does not have a property `value`. If you wonder why `val1.value` exists: `val1` holds a reference to some HTML form element which has a property `value`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use the function parseInt() to transform the string stored in val1.value into a number:

```
var val2 = parseInt(val1.value) + 1;
```

Note that `Number(val1.value)` will also convert your value into a number.

**-edit-**
As yc suggest, is highly recommended to use `parseInt(val1.value, 10) + 1;` because if your string starts with a `"0"` the string is interpreted as octal. eg. `parseInt("0123") == 83` and not 123

Comment: Don't forget to add the second argument in `parseInt()` of 10, so it doesn't mistakenly evaluate as an octal.

Comment: Better yet, don't use `parseInt()` at all if you don't need to, just use `+` or `Number()`, neither of those parse octals. e.g. `+val1.value + 1`. `parseInt()` is mainly for extracting numbers from the start of strings, so as long as your string is a valid numeric literal, you don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and also preferred way would be to use `+` to cast to a number.

**Examples:**

```
+'234'; // 234
+'042'; // 42! It does not convert to octal
```

**In your case:**

```
var val1 = +(document.getElementById('<%= rng1.ClientID %>').value); // () added just for the looks
var val2 = val1.value + 1; // if val1 is 5, val2 will be 6 hooray!
alert(val2); // just val2, since it's a plain number not an html input element
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt($('.scpContainer').height()+200)
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add number, so try it without quotes :-)

Comment: and also use parseInt() for the other value

Answer (score 0):

In an external JavaScript file you can't use the `<%=ControlID.ClientID %>` to get the client id.

If there you using an external JavaScript file you need to pass client id value to that function.